# Multiple selection using shift arrow broken after programmatically selecting a line in Delphi ListView

Tags: listview, delphi, multi-select, ownerdrawn, virtuallistview

I am using a both owner draw and data listview in a Delphi and I noticed a weird problem if I select using shift arrow immediately after having first programmatically changed the selected line the selection.

Consider the following window where I have tried to display the problem with minimal code:

[image: Shift Down selection gets messed up]

And here is the minimal Delphi code that replicates the problem:

```
unit Main;

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//    I N T E R F A C E
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

interface uses Classes,
               ComCtrls,
               Controls,
               Dialogs,
               ExtCtrls,
               Forms,
               Graphics,
               Messages,
               StdCtrls,
               SysUtils,
               Variants,
               Windows;

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//    T Y P E      D E F I N I T I O N S
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type TMainForm = class(TForm)

    listView             : TListView;

    bottomPanel          : TPanel;

        position10Button : TButton;

    procedure FormCreate(
                  sender : TObject);

    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //    LIST VIEW EVENT HANDLERS
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    procedure ListViewData(
                  sender : TObject;
                  item   : TListItem);

    procedure ListViewDrawItem(
                  sender : TCustomListView;
                  item   : TListItem;
                  rect   : TRect;
                  state  : TOwnerDrawState);

    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //    POSITION BUTTON HANDLER
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    procedure Position10ButtonClick(
                  sender : TObject);

private

    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //    WINDOWS MESSAGE HANDLERS
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    procedure WMMeasureItem(
                  var msg : TWMMeasureItem);    message WM_MEASUREITEM;

private

    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //    DRAWING
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    procedure DrawHighlightRect(
                  canvas : TCanvas;
                  rect   : TRect;
                  color  : TColor);

end;

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//    G L O B A L     V A R I A B L E S
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

var MainForm : TMainForm;

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//    I M P L E M E N T A T I O N
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

implementation uses CommCtrl;

{$R *.dfm}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//    F O R M     C R E A T E
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

procedure TMainForm.FormCreate(
                        sender : TObject);
begin
  //  Set double buffering for listview.

  listView.doubleBuffered := TRUE;

  //  Set listview count: 20 lines.

  listView.items.count := 20;

  //  Set focus on listview.

  WINDOWS.SetFocus(
              listView.handle);
end;

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//    FORM CONTROLS EVENT HANDLERS
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//    LIST VIEW EVENT HANDLERS
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//    L I S T V I E W     D A T A
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

procedure TMainForm.ListViewData(
                        sender : TObject;
                        item   : TListItem);

begin
  if item = NIL then EXIT;

  item.caption := SYSUTILS.IntToStr(item.index);
end;

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//    L I S T V I E W     D R A W     I T E M
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

procedure TMainForm.ListViewDrawItem(
                        sender : TCustomListView;
                        item   : TListItem;
                        rect   : TRect;
                        state  : TOwnerDrawState);

  const TEXT_MARGIN = 7;

  var drawRect : TRect;

begin
  //  Draw focus rectangle for selected item.

  if item.selected then
    begin
      drawRect := rect;

      Inc( drawRect.top,   1);
      Dec( drawRect.bottom,1);

      DrawHighlightRect(
          sender.canvas,
          drawRect,
          clBlack);
    end;

  //  Prepare brush to draw text.

  sender.canvas.brush.style := bsClear;

  //  Draw text.

  drawRect       := rect;
  drawRect.left  := TEXT_MARGIN;

  WINDOWS.DrawText(
              sender.canvas.handle,
              PCHAR(item.caption),
              Length( item.caption),
              drawRect,
              DT_SINGLELINE or
              DT_LEFT       or
              DT_VCENTER);
end;

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//    P O S I T I O N     1 0     B U T T O N     C L I C K
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

procedure TMainForm.Position10ButtonClick(
                        sender : TObject);
begin
  WINDOWS.SetFocus(
              listView.handle);

  //  Unselect all.

  listView.ClearSelection;

  //  Select and focus line 10.

  listview.items[10].selected := TRUE;
  listview.items[10].focused  := TRUE;
end;

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//    WINDOWS MESSAGE HANDLERS
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//    W M     M E A S U R E     I T E M
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

procedure TMainForm.WMMeasureItem(
                        var msg : TWMMeasureItem);
begin
  inherited;

  //  Set height of list view items.

  if msg.IDCtl = listView.handle then msg.measureItemStruct^.itemHeight := 25;
end;

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//    D R A W     H I G H L I G H T     R E C T
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

procedure TMainForm.DrawHighlightRect(
                        canvas : TCanvas;
                        rect   : TRect;
                        color  : TColor);

  var topLeft              : TPoint;
  var topRight             : TPoint;
  var bottomRight          : TPoint;
  var bottomLeft           : TPoint;

begin
  //  Prepare pen.

  canvas.pen.style := psSolid;
  canvas.pen.width := 1;
  canvas.pen.mode  := pmCopy;

  //  Compute outer rectangle points.

  topLeft.x     := rect.left;
  topLeft.y     := rect.top;

  topRight.x    := rect.right;
  topRight.y    := rect.top;

  bottomRight.x := rect.right;
  bottomRight.y := rect.bottom;

  bottomLeft.x  := rect.left;
  bottomLeft.y  := rect.bottom;

  //  Draw rectangle.

  canvas.pen.color := color;

  canvas.PolyLine( [ topLeft, topRight, bottomRight, bottomLeft, topLeft]);

  //  Compute inner rectangle points.

  topLeft.x     := rect.left   + 1;
  topLeft.y     := rect.top    + 1;

  topRight.x    := rect.right  - 1;
  topRight.y    := rect.top    + 1;

  bottomRight.x := rect.right  - 1;
  bottomRight.y := rect.bottom - 1;

  bottomLeft.x  := rect.left   + 1;
  bottomLeft.y  := rect.bottom - 1;

  //  Draw rectangle.

  canvas.pen.color := color;

  canvas.PolyLine( [ topLeft, topRight, bottomRight, bottomLeft, topLeft]);
end;

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

end.
```

[Edit]
As pointed out by Andreas Rejbrand, the problem also exists with a non-ownerdraw non-ownerdata listview.

```
unit Main;

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//    I N T E R F A C E
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


interface uses Classes,
               ComCtrls,
               Controls,
               Dialogs,
               ExtCtrls,
               Forms,
               Graphics,
               Messages,
               StdCtrls,
               SysUtils,
               Variants,
               Windows;

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//    T Y P E      D E F I N I T I O N S
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type TMainForm = class(TForm)

    listView             : TListView;

    bottomPanel          : TPanel;

        position10Button : TButton;

    procedure FormCreate(
                  sender : TObject);

    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //    POSITION BUTTON HANDLER
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    procedure Position10ButtonClick(
                  sender : TObject);

end;

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//    G L O B A L     V A R I A B L E S
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

var MainForm : TMainForm;

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//    I M P L E M E N T A T I O N
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

implementation uses CommCtrl;

{$R *.dfm}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//    F O R M     C R E A T E
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

procedure TMainForm.FormCreate(
                        sender : TObject);

  var index   : integer;
  var newItem : TListItem;

begin
  //  Set double buffering for listview.

  listView.doubleBuffered := TRUE;

  for index := 0 to 19 do
    begin
      newItem := listview.items.Add;
      newItem.caption := SYSUTILS.IntToStr( index);
    end;

  //  Set focus on listview.

  WINDOWS.SetFocus(
              listView.handle);
end;

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//    FORM CONTROLS EVENT HANDLERS
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//    P O S I T I O N     1 0     B U T T O N     C L I C K
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

procedure TMainForm.Position10ButtonClick(
                        sender : TObject);
begin
  WINDOWS.SetFocus(
              listView.handle);

  //  Unselect all.

  listView.ClearSelection;

  //  Select and focus line 10.

  listview.items[10].selected := TRUE;
  listview.items[10].focused  := TRUE;
end;

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

end.
```

Comment: Maybe a bit nitpicking, but your "miminal" example surely isn't minimal, and yet it isn't complete. For instance, you can reproduce the issue even if you disable both owner data and owner draw!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that the "minimal" example in your Q contains *a lot* of unnecessary code. You can reproduce this issue without both owner drawing and owner data. Just drop a new `TListView` control on a form, add a few items in the IDE, and set `MultiSelect` to `True`. (*)

Now, the trick is to use the [`LVM_SETSELECTIONMARK`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/lvm-setselectionmark) message, or the [`ListView_SetSelectionMark`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/nf-commctrl-listview_setselectionmark) function (in Delphi):

```
ListView1.ClearSelection;
ListView1.ItemIndex := 10;
ListView_SetSelectionMark(ListView1.Handle, 10)
```

(*) And, of course, you need to enable double buffering to avoid all the horrible visual glitches you get otherwise.

Comment: Andreas, you are right the problem arises also without ownerdata and ownerdraw. Thanks for the SetSelectionMark trick, but I had to replace your "ListView1.itemIndex := 10" line by "ListView1.items[10].selected := TRUE; ListView1.items[10].focused := TRUE;" to get it working.

Comment: Andreas, unless proven otherwise, setting the item to focused is important. If you confirm and edit your solution, I will be happy to accept it. And thanks again for making me discover the ListView_SetSelectionMark API. :-)

Comment: @EmmanuelIchbiah: I am unable to confirm that in the simpler context I outlined above in Delphi 10.3.2 and Windows 7 (64-bit). I haven't tried it in your context.

Comment: I am using Windows 10 (64-bit) and setting the focused state is needed.

Comment: @EmmanuelIchbiah: In the simple context (new VCL app, drop list view, set `MultiSelect`, add 20 items using the IDE)? Do you also use Delphi 10.3.2? What exactly happens if you only use my code above?

Comment: Interesting, your solution works with Delphi 10.2.3 but not with Delphi 2007. I must say I am surprised to see that setting the focused state makes a difference because the documentation says that when only one element is selected, it is also automatically focused.

Answer (score 0):

In your `ListViewDrawItem()` handler, `if item.selected then` should be `if odSelected in state then`

But also, in your `Position10ButtonClick()` handler, you are setting a particular item's `Selected` and `Focused` properties, but you need to do those assignments in the `OnData` event instead, which you are not currently doing.  You need to save the selection details somewhere off to the side and then apply that info in the `OnData` event.  You will also need to handle the `OnSelectItem` event and save the details that it gives you when the user makes changes to the current selection.

Try something like this:

```pascal
type
  MyListItemInfo = record
    Caption: String;
    Selected: Boolean;
    Focused: Boolean;
  end;

private
  MyListItems: array of MyListItemInfo;

procedure TMainForm.FormCreate(
                        Sender : TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  //  Set double buffering for listview.

  ListView.DoubleBuffered := True;

  //  Set listview count: 20 lines.

  SetLength(MyListItems, 20);

  for I := Low(MyListItems) to High(MyListItems) do
  begin
    MyListItems[I].Caption := SysUtils.IntToStr(I);
    MyListItems[I].Selected := False;
    MyListItems[I].Focused := False;
  end;

  ListView.Items.Count := Length(MyListItems);

  //  Set focus on listview.

  ListView.SetFocus;
end;

procedure TMainForm.ListViewSelectItem(
                        Sender  : TObject;
                        Item    : TListItem;
                        Selected: Boolean);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  if Item <> nil then
  begin
    MyListItems[Item.Index].Selected := Selected;
    ListView.UpdateItems(Item.Index, Item.Index);
  end else
  begin
    for I := 0 to listView.Items.Count-1 do
      MyListItems[I].Selected := Selected;
    ListView.Invalidate;
  end;
end;

procedure TMainForm.ListViewData(
                        Sender : TObject;
                        Item   : TListItem);

begin
  Item.Caption := MyListItems[Item.Index].Caption;
  Item.Selected := MyListItems[Item.Index].Selected;
  item.Focused := MyListItems[Item.Index].Focused;
end;

procedure TMainForm.Position10ButtonClick(
                        Sender : TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  ListView.SetFocus;

  //  Unselect all.

  ListView.ClearSelection;

  for I := Low(MyListItems) to High(MyListItems) do
  begin
    MyListItems[I].Selected := False;
    MyListItems[I].Focused := False;
  end;

  //  Select and focus line 10.

  MyListItems[10].Selected := True;
  MyListItems[10].Focused := True;

  ListView.Invalidate;
end;
```

Comment: Hi Remy, thank you so much for your help. I have always assumed that OnData was to set the caption and the subitems if present. What I like about the solution using SetSelectionMark is that it works for any listview regardless of its ownerdata status. As Andreas pointed out the problem I faced was not specific to ownerdata listviews.

Comment: "*I have always assumed that OnData was to set the caption and the subitems if present*" - it is for providing *any* of the *per-item data* that you need, not just the caption. For instance, state and image indexes, too.  That is what makes an owner-data ListView be virtual - the data is not stored in the ListView, you provide the data on-demand.

Comment: I end up having a "selected" attribute in my data anyway. Where I am more skeptical is about maintaining the "focused" attribute. When you click a line (without holding shift or cotnrol) the listview internally knows that the clicked line becomes the focused entry. In your OnSelectItem you don't really know if you need to set the focused state or not. I think it is probably wiser to rely on the ListView itself to maintain its focused state info. Don't you think so.

Comment: `TListView` only exposes events for selection changes and checkbox state changes, but not for focus changes. However, the underlying `LVN_ITEMCHANGING` and `LVN_ITEMCHANGED` notifications do provide this information.

Comment: OK. I see some leeway there. I am not convinced that the problem I was experiencing is due to the lack of information (selected & focused) given in the OnData handler, all the more as the problem occurs also with a non-ownerdata ListView.

Comment: I forgot to add that you also need to maintain 'selected' in the OnDataStateChange event. Interestingly the startIndex and endIndex contain the wrong range explaining the selection mess. So I think it is a ListView bug and the use of the ListView_SetSelectionMark is just a workaround to circumvent it.

Comment: @EmmanuelIchbiah I've never had a problem like that with the `OnData..`. events. But then, I've never needed to use `MultiSelect=true` with `OwnerData=true`, either.

Answer (score 0):

Worth to mention, there is a bug (at least in Embarcadero 10.3) - NewState and OldState are passed in the wrong (swapped) order:

```
Vcl.ComCtrls.pas (line 19375):
    LVN_ODSTATECHANGED:
        with NMLVODStateChange{$IFNDEF CLR}^{$ENDIF} do
            OwnerDataStateChange(iFrom, iTo, ConvertStates(uNewState), ConvertStates(uOldState));

Vcl.ComCtrls.pas (line 18887):
      function TCustomListView.OwnerDataStateChange(StartIndex, EndIndex: Integer;
        OldState, NewState: TItemStates): Boolean;
      begin
        if Assigned(FOnDataStateChange) then
            begin
                FOnDataStateChange(Self, StartIndex, EndIndex, OldState, NewState);
                Result := True;
            end
        else Result := False;
      end;
```